# Difference between compound assignment and operator

Tags: c++, overloading, addition, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I want to overload two operators: 
+=
and 
+

what is basically the difference between them?
is += just modifying the current object and + returns a new object?

Comment: Yes. `lhs += rhs` should increment `lhs` by `rhs`, and `lhs + rhs` should leave both unchanged, and return the result of the addition.

Comment: Pretty much what you said, yes.

Comment: `+=` usually also returns reference to changed variable.

Comment: You can often write one in terms of the other, to reduce duplication of code. (Usually + is written to make use of +=.)

Answer (score 4):

It's just like you said, operator+= works in-place (it modifies the current object), while operator+ returns a new object and leaves its parameters unchanged.

A common way to implement them for a type `T` is as follows:

```
// operator+= is a member function of T
T& T::operator+=(const T& rhs)
{
    // perform the addition
    return *this;
}

// operator+ is a free function...
T operator+(T lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    // ...implemented in terms of operator+=
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```